# React.createElement is giving 'Component is not defined' error

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to use the [react-stockcharts](https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts) package in my project.

Also, I'm trying to create a Web Component which encapsulates the stock chart.

While trying to do a React.createElement(ChartComponent, { prop: value }) I'm getting an error 'ChartComponent is not defined'.

Here is my code for creating the web component (deploymentbox.html):

```
<template id="MyChartTemplate">
  <ChartComponent />
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/main.e36f828b.js"></script>

<script>
const t = (document.currentScript||document._currentScript).ownerDocument.querySelector('#MyChartTemplate');

function updateChart(chartComponent, id) {
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(ChartComponent, { data_url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/deployment/deploymentbox/"+id }), t)
}

var MyChartElementPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

MyChartElementPrototype.createdCallback = function () {
    var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
    updateChart(clone.querySelector('ChartComponent'), this.getAttribute("id") || "");
    this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
};

var MyChartElement = document.registerElement('my-chart', {
    prototype: MyChartElementPrototype
});
</script>
```

The *main.e36f828b.js* file is generated by webpack.

Here is the code for using the web component in an HTML page (boxtest.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>My Component Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="import" href="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/deployment/deploymentbox/">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart">
      <my-chart id=1 />
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the definition of ChartComponent (included in the *main.e36f828b.js* file):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Chart from './chart';
import { getData } from "./utils"

import { TypeChooser } from "react-stockcharts/lib/helper";

class ChartComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.data_url = this.props.data_url
        getData(data_url).then(data => {
            this.setState({ data : data })
        })
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state == null) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <TypeChooser>
                {type => <Chart type={type} data={this.state.data} />}
            </TypeChooser>
        )
    }
}

export default ChartComponent;
```

This code (in the last code snippet) has been picked up (with minor changes) from the react-stockcharts CandleSticks example found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2/tree/master/examples/CandleStickChartForDiscontinuousIntraDay).

Why am I getting the error? Am I missing something simple in this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you importing in ChartComponent?

Comment: @dmikester1 Do I need to import it explicitly? I thought that because I'm including main.e36f828b.js (via a <script src=""> tag, and because ChartComponent is exported in main.e36f828b.js, it would be imported.

Comment: I'm confused.  Isn't your main.xxxx.js rendered and built code?  You should be importing ChartComponent into your component where you use it.  Why are you messing with that main.xxxx.js file?  You shouldn't ever need to explicitly call that ever in your code.

Comment: Your react code should never be loading anything from the dist folder.  You create your react app and when it is all ready to go or just to test, you build it and and that creates the dist folder which is the actual code you would throw up on your production server.

Comment: @dmikester1 Sorry for the confusion, I'm new to React. I'm not messing with the main.xxx.js file. I've just included it in the html because it contains the ChartComponent. I thought that was the way to import ChartComponent. Could you tell me how do I import ChartComponent?

Comment: No worries, I was very new to React myself not too long ago. :)  You would import ChartComponent just like you would anything else.  At the top of your file you use it: `import ChartComponent from 'chart-component';`  Obviously, change that to fit your environment.

Comment: Make sure you remove the include to the webpack built file.  I'm not sure what that would even do, but it probably will produce some strange undesirable effects.

Comment: what folder is deploymentbox.html in?

Comment: @dmikester1 I am kind of working with a different config than the usual config created with create-react-app. I am using python/flask server on the client side and the reactjs on the client side. Kind of like at this link: https://itnext.io/a-template-for-creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-flask-npm-webpack-and-reactjs-be2294b111bd